# Why do I get a slider with modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

I am getting a slider next to my modal like this:

[image: this]

My code for the modal is:

```
 div#myModal.modal.fade.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2(tabindex="-1", role="dialog", aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true")
    div.modal-content
        div.modal-body
            p Modal body content.
        div.modal-footer
            button.btn.btn-default(type="button", data-dismiss="modal") Close
```

And I invoke the modal from `javascript`:

```
  $('#joinBtn').click(function(event) {
        $('#myModal').modal({
        show: true
    })
});
```

Comment: You need to add `overflow:hidden` to the containing element

Comment: What do you mean by containing element? Because I've added to the `#myModal` div and it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add

```
 div#myModal.modal.fade.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2(tabindex="-1", role="dialog", aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="overflow-y: auto;")
```

or in your CSS you could add:

```
.modal {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Fir some reason modifying the css does not work, but defining explicitly the `style` does.

Comment: @Pio maybe try doing it on the id? So `#myModal{
    overflow-y: auto;
}`

Comment: That is almost the same as specifying explicitly. I mean it will act only upon that specific modal. But it's OK.

Comment: It was actually my bad. I included my custom style before bootstrap.